# Trying to get values to equal

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class javascript {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
Random rand = new Random();

int door1 = 0;
int door2 = 0;
int door3 = 0;
int gdoor1 = 0;
int gdoor2 = 0;
int gdoor3 = 0;
int cdoor = 0;
door1 = rand.nextInt(3)+1;  
door2 = rand.nextInt(3)+1;  
door3 = rand.nextInt(3)+1;  

if (door1 == door2 || door1 == door3){
    door1 = rand.nextInt(3)+1;
}
if (door2 == door1 || door2 == door3){
    door2 = rand.nextInt(3)+1;
}
if (door3 == door1 || door3 == door2){
    door3 = rand.nextInt(3)+1;
}

System.out.println("Choose A Door");
System.out.println(" _____      _____       _____ ");
System.out.println("|     |    |     |     |     |");
System.out.println("|  1  |    |  2  |     |  3  |");
System.out.println("|     |    |     |     |     |");
System.out.println("|     |    |     |     |     |");
System.out.println("|_____|    |_____|     |_____|");
System.out.println("\n");


int yourdoor = scan.nextInt();
System.out.println("Your Door: "+yourdoor); 

if (door1 == 1 || door1 == 2){
    door1 = gdoor1;}
if (door2 == 1 || door1 == 2){
    door2 = gdoor2;}
if (door3 == 1 || door1 == 2){
    door3 = gdoor3;}

if(door1 == 3){
    door1 = cdoor;}
if(door2 == 3){
    door2 = cdoor;}
if(door3 == 3){
    door3 = cdoor;}

System.out.println("Value = "+cdoor);




    }
}
```

I am making the Monty Hall game show. I am new to this and i just am wondering why at the end when i print out the cdoor why does it always print out 0. I want it to print out the value 3 because i thought they would equal because of --This Part

```
    if(door1 == 3){
        door1 = cdoor;}
    if(door2 == 3){
        door2 = cdoor;}
    if(door3 == 3){
        door3 = cdoor;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `cdoor` is always 0. It is never modified. Perhaps you meant,

```
if (door1 == 3) {
    cdoor = door1;
}
if (door2 == 3) {
    cdoor = door2;
}
if (door3 == 3) {
    cdoor = door3;
}
```

Comment: I have another problem...                                                                                       When i randomize the values of door1, door2, and door3      i kept getting repeating numbers so i put those if's in there to re-randomize them but it didnt work. Any suggestions       @Flying_Banana

Comment: Because you are randomizing again, and since the new value can be anything from 1-3, you have 33% chance of getting the same value. Instead, you should randomly choose between 1-3, then randomly choose between 1-2 (or 1 3 or 2 3, depending on what the first door's number is), and finally the last door will have the leftover number instead.

Comment: But i don't understand because isn't the if saying that it'll keep randomizing the doors until they don't equal one another? @Flying_Banana

Comment: It says it'll randomize *once* if the first time we did it they equal to each other. You can put in a while loop, if you wish.